# Antlr vs NLTK in Jython

Tags: nlp, antlr, nltk, text-mining

I am currently writing an NLP project in java that tags and parses text. My main issue is with the parsing component, it is currently using Antlr to convert the tagged text into a parse tree. Since Antlr isn't primarily written as a NL parsing tool, it takes up a lot of memory and is not easily adaptable for modifying the grammar. I would like to use NLTK  within jython to solve this issue, would this be recommended especially considering that this is a distributed project, or is there a neat java equivalent to produce these parse trees.

Thanks

Comment: Coercing parsing tools for formal languages, such as ANTLR, into NLP tools, never really works. They're not designed to handle the kind of ambiguity that occurs in natural language, let alone the frequent updates to the grammar.

Answer (score 3):

You're right: ANTLR is not well suited for things like this.

I have no experience with NLTK, but have tried to do some "heavy lifting" through Jython which didn't pan out too well.

The [Stanford Natural Language Processing Group](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/) have a good NL parser. That is, I've heard good things about it, I am by no means an expert in NLP!

Here's how you can parse a simple English sentence like `"I am currently writing an NLP project in Java that tags and parses text."`:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StanfordParserDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // englishPCFG.ser.gz is in the download. 
    LexicalizedParser parser = new LexicalizedParser("/path/to/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
    TokenizerFactory<Word> tokenFactory = PTBTokenizer.factory(false, new WordTokenFactory());

    String sentence = "I am currently writing an NLP project in Java that tags and parses text.";
    System.out.println("Sentence: " + sentence);

    List<Word> words = tokenFactory.getTokenizer(new StringReader(sentence)).tokenize();
    parser.parse(words);

    Tree tree = parser.getBestParse();
    TreePrint treePrinter = new TreePrint("penn,typedDependenciesCollapsed");
    treePrinter.printTree(tree);
  }
}
```

which prints:

```
Sentence: I am currently writing an NLP project in java that tags and parses text.
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP I))
    (VP (VBP am)
      (ADVP (RB currently))
      (VP (VBG writing)
        (NP (DT an) (NNP NLP) (NN project))
        (PP (IN in)
          (NP (NN java)))
        (SBAR (IN that)
          (S
            (NP (NNS tags)
              (CC and)
              (NNS parses))
            (VP (VBZ text))))))
    (. .)))
```

The JAR and grammars for various languages can be downloaded [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-parser-2011-06-27.tgz).

Comment: Thank you!
I have looked into the Stanford Parser but my problem with it is that it is model based; and I couldn't find a way to add my own grammar rules to it in a similar way to NLTK's chunk parser.

Comment: @LEzan, ah, so you're only interested in a small part of the input source/language, if I understand correctly. If so, could you give an example in your original question: there is a small chance the ANTLR _can_ be used.

Comment: Well I am currently using Antlr but the rules are getting too big for it to handle effectively. Basically I want something that takes some rules as input and produces a tree as output.

So for example if I gave it there rules:

`S: NP VP
NP: DT ADJ+ NN
VP:  VB*`
And passed it this sentence : "The quick fox jumped"; then
I would like to get:
(S
  (NP (DT The)
      (ADJ quick)
      (NN fox)
  )
  (VP (VBD jumped))
)

Thanks

Comment: @Lezan, no only when you're parsing just a (small) part of the natural language could ANTLR _perhaps_ be used. Your latest comment does not suggest this, in which case I don't recommend you use ANTLR.

Comment: Thank you and yes I know Antlr is proving to be quite difficult when its a wide NL domain but am yet to find something else that does this